# Saturated classes, generation by a set and pullbacks of categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, accessible-categories, locally-presentable-categories

Assume that we have a pullback square 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \rightarrow & B \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
C & \rightarrow & D \\
\end{array} 
$$
with all functors accessible, and all categories presentable (if needed, assume that $A \to C$ and $B \to D$ are left adjoints).

Suppose further that we have three saturated (that is, closed under retracts, pushouts and transfinite compositions) classes of arrows $S(B),S(C),S(D)$ of,
respectively, $B,C,D$. Assume that the functors $B \to D, C \to D$ preserve these classes. (It seems likely to me that the set $S(D)$ should not play any importance in what follows)

Form the set $S(A)$ by requiring that it consists of all arrows of $A$ that are sent to $S(B)$ and $S(C)$ by the respective functors.

Question: if $S(B),S(C),S(D)$ are generated by (small) sets, does it imply that $S(A)$ is generated by a set as well?

EDIT: it may be not obvious that the formed class S(A) is weakly saturated. Assume it is.

EDIT2: I do not know if the original question admits an affirmative answer. What is true is that, following a remark of Tim to this post, one can consider the situation with the right classes. Let me leave a statement 
that may be of use for someone who googles this post up.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be a presentable category together with a weak factorisation system $(L,R)$ having the property that

1. $(L,R)$ is functorial (a closer inspection may be used to drop this),
2. The functor $A^{[1]} \to A^{[2]}$ associated to the weak factorisation system is accessible,
3. The right class $R$ viewed as a subcategory of $A^{[1]}$ is accessible and accessibly embedded.

Then there exists a set $L_0 \subset L$ generating $(L,R)$.

Comment: No colimit preservation for $C\to D$ might be assumed?

Comment: Ideally, no. The example I have in mind is the category of sections of a Grothendieck fibration $E \to [1]$ such that $E(0),E(1)$ are presentable and $E(1) \to E(0)$ is accessible, with no evident adjoint.

Comment: The hypotheses feel a bit awkward, suggesting to me that this is not the right abstraction to work with. However, if you look at the corresponding right classes $R(B),R(C)$ of of these wfs, then if you define $R(A) = R(B) \times_{D^{[1]}} R(C)$ it will be accessible and accessibly embedded (as the pullback of such along accessible functors). So assuming that $R(A)$ is again the right class of a wfs, the left class corresponding to $R(A)$ will be small-generated.

Comment: Tim: thank you, I think your comment solves one particular case I am looking in.

Comment: @TimCampion could you please provide a reference for the statement that you mention? Namely that an accessible and accessibly embedded subcategory of $A^{[1]}$ is generated by a set of morphisms of $A$. I only find one for small injectivity-classes, which does not quite give the same. Thank you.

Comment: @TimCampion alright I think I see it; you assumed however that the factorisation corresponding to the wfs is accessible, I suppose?

Comment: I'm actually having trouble justifying my claim. I'm sorry, that was sloppy of me. I suppose that leaves the question open.

Comment: @TimCampion I dont though! :) The idea is to show that the functor $Fib_\lambda /f \subset (A^{[1]})_\lambda/f$ is cofinal, and this amounts to saying that a map between $\lambda$-presentable objects factors in the wfs with the middle object being $\lambda$-presentable. So some assumption is still needed on the wfs in question. Thanks for your idea it was of use indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see Theorem 3.2 in Makkai and Rosický's Cellular categories.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. They seem to assume that both $C \to D$ and $B \to D$ preserve colimits, which is not exactly my case. Do you reckon that the proof goes through still?

Comment: I don't think S(A) is always weakly saturated under such conditions.  If you do know it is weakly saturated, then Tim Campion's argument should suffice.